# Transformer's transform causes a fatal error, why?

Tags: java, xml, jaxp

I've built a document using JAXP like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.newDocument();
Element rootElement = document.createElement("Root");

for (MyObject o : myCollection) {
    Element entry = document.createElement("Entry");
    Element entryItem = document.createElement("EntryItem");
    entryItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(o.getProperty()));

    entry.appendChild(entryItem);
    rootElement.appendChild(entry);
}

document.appendChild(rootElement);
```

Now, when I try to output the XML for the document like this:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
transformer.transform(source, result);
System.out.println(result.getWriter().toString());
```

It falls apart on the `transformer.transform` line with the following error:

```
FATAL ERROR:  'java.lang.NullPointerException'
       :null
```

How do I go about debugging this? I've made sure that `transformer`, `source` and `result` aren't null.

Comment: Anyone want to hazard a guess?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that this:

```
entryItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(o.getProperty()));
```

created a text node with a null value. Looking at Xerces' code (which is the default JAXP implementation shipped with Oracle's JDK 1.6), I see no null validation done at the time of constructing the text node. I suspect that that, later, makes the `Transformer` die.

Either that, or there's some JAXp configuration problem.

You may wish to set the `jaxp.debug` system property (available JDK 1.6+) to get some JAXP tracing information.

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond to this sooner, I must have missed the notification of responses on SO. I'll get back to updating the question tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

--How about the document?

Ooops sorry, obviously the second part follows the first :) Which parser are you using?